# PHP locale configuration in php.ini

Tags: locale, php

Can a default locale value be placed in file *php.ini* or *.htaccess*?

The equivalent of the PHP function

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
```

for example.

Answer (score 8):

It can. Take a look at [`intl.default_locale`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.configuration.php#ini.intl.default-locale).

Comment: From the manual: "The locale that will be used **in intl functions** when none is specified (either by omitting the corresponding argument or by passing NULL). These are ICU locales, **not system locales**. ..."

Comment: @HalilÖzgür Whatever that means... PHP is weird.

Comment: It's been a while and I agree in general but, I've tried to come up with a clearer explanation and failed :) Could you clarify the part(s) that sound weird?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the *php.ini* file to help you. But as an alternative you could try setting environment variables from file *.htaccess*:

```
SetEnv   LC_ALL  it_IT.UTF-8
```

But these settings only take effect for the CGI and [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) versions of PHP at best, not for the usual *[mod_php](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache_modules)* installation.

Comment: Any idea how to do set the locale when using `nginx` and `php-fpm`?

Comment: PHP is not inheriting ENV locales anymore : https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/c4ad8beaa890b931031a5cf8a1d2d38550fca3af

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no way at this time to set this configuration PHP-wide.
I've been looking at the code and the *ENV* method doesn't work since `LC_*` variables are not treated like the other ones.

You can patch PHP to use your locale instead of the default `'C'` one or make a module if you really need to.

But the actual way to go is to do it at the script level.

Using *auto_prepend_file* in *php.ini* lets you run add some code before any script executed, so it looks like a nice place to use setlocale.