# php - can't get date in german language

Tags: php, date, setlocale

I try to display a date in German but it doesn't work. I'm using PHP with XAMPP.

These are my approaches:

```
function get_Datetime_Now() {
setlocale (LC_TIME, "de_DE");
$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Zurich');
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);     
return $datetime->format('l, d. F Y  ');
}

echo get_Datetime_Now();
```

It returns "Sunday, 09. February 2014" but I wan't "Sonntag, 09. Februar 2014" (German language).

I also tried this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
echo strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y");
```

It also returns "Sunday, 09. February 2014". I saw many examples on the internet, which don't work (at least on my environment).

Are there settings that I should check?

I appreciate any help!

Thx in advance, 
shivan

Comment: Any chance you are using a windows system?

Comment: what if using setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.utf8");

Comment: XAMPP is Windows only.

Comment: Please refer Post: [German language in php date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439130/how-can-i-support-the-german-language-in-php-datetime-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably using a windows machine which has different language codes in PHP than a Unix based one.

Try:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
```

This will first try to set it to `'de_DE'` (Linux/Unix) and have the `'deu_deu'` code as a fallback for windows (PHP Version >= 4.3).

[Example in the german PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-examples)

Comment: Hmm, marked myself as NooB. ;) Actually  N O  way for that in `php.ini`? Wow. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar I didn't say that there is no way to set the locale in the `php.ini`. I was simply complaining, that you were suggesting changing the `php.ini` without actually naming what changes should be made.

Comment: Yeah, I did first, but aimed for something with date and some local settings, (but it was `timezone`, there the -1 came from;) and posted that, but I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075145/php-locale-configuration-in-php-ini did a quick google and gave up. ;) (y)

Comment: Btw, your answer was the only right popping up.! +1

Comment: I tried using the same question code and tried using the most upvoted answer as the solution but it returns value in english iteslf . How come is that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'de_DE.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y");
```

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I just comment to thank [Tim Bodeit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984384/tim-bodeit), and if someone is looking to set the month in spanish, this is the code that worked to me:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'esp_esp');
```

Answer (score 0):

The locale parameters are others compared linux to windows

See here:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Usually it's "DEU" or "GERMAN" under Win.