# PHP get next month issue

Tags: php, time, strftime

I'm trying to get the current, the next and the after next month by php.

This is my current php:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.utf8");
$thismonth = strftime("%B");
$nextmonth = strftime( '%B', strtotime( '+1 month', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year ) ) );
$overnextmonth = strftime( '%B', strtotime( '+2 month', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year ) ) );
```

The month name should be in german so I'm using `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.utf8");`.

The ouput is: Januar (january), Januar (january), Februar (february). I can't figure the issue out.

Comment: check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661218/php-cant-get-date-in-german-language

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: month in ......

Comment: Where does `$month` and `$year` come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this `setlocale (LC_TIME,"de_DE");` it will work

```
<?php
setlocale (LC_TIME,"de_DE"); 
echo $thismonth = strftime("%B");
echo $nextmonth = strftime( '%B', strtotime( '+1 month', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2017 ) ) );
echo $overnextmonth = strftime( '%B', strtotime( '+2 month', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2017 ) ) );

?>
```

output

[output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Mil.png)

Comment: instead of $month & $year i put normal value 2017 for year & 1 for month

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to move away from strtotime and use the php dateTime class.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // <-- adds 1 month to the current
echo $date->format('F') . "\n"; // it's now January so it outputs February
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $date->format('F') . "\n"; // adds one more (total 2) months from original
```

Current month is January. This output will be "February March"