# How can I support the German language in PHP DateTime object?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

How can I change the days in German format like Tuesday = Dienstag (Tue = Die)

```
$ed = new DateTime('03/20/2018');
$e_day_name = $ed->format('D');

var_dump( $e_day_name );
```

> string(3) "Tue"
>
> I want [string(3) "Die"]

Comment: By setting the locale and timezone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - can't get date in german language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661218/php-cant-get-date-in-german-language)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a short example, which is not mentioned in the possible duplicate comment by Raunak Gupta. It uses the native IntlDateFormatter class, which is available since PHP 5.3. You don 't have to set the default timezone every time in a multilanguage environment.

```
// the date time object 
$date = new DateTime('2013-02-25'); 

// the international date formater object
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter( 
    "de-DE", 
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG, 
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
    "Europe/Berlin", 
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 
    "EEEE', der' dd. MMMM YYYY" 
); 

echo $formatter->format($date); // Montag, der 25. Februar 2013
```

Easy, hm? ;)

More about the IntlDateFormatter class and its parameters in the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's really helpful :)