# Decimal comma instead of decimal point

Tags: php

How can I change a decimal point to decimal comma by setting it in php.ini **without any changes in code** on my local server running on Windows?

```
3.14 >> 3,14
```

I tried to set

```
intl.default_locale = cs_CZ
```

without any results.

**EDIT**: The reason why I'm asking is that if I execute the code on hosting I get numbers with decimal comma, but when I transfer same code to my local server there is a decimal point. Where is the catch?

For example - Linux hosting:

```
echo 100 / 3; // 33,333333333333
```

Local server on Windows:

```
echo 100 / 3; // 33.333333333333
```

What is the reason?

**EDIT 2**: If I use

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'cs_CZ');
echo 100 / 3;
```

I will get the same result **33.333333333333**, so the catch must be in configuration files or in Windows itself.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? If you're going to use them as decimals, then why not store it as such? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/220538) to me. Maybe you could add more explanation as to what you're trying to achieve -- that way, you'd get *more* accurate answers.

Comment: Because in Czech Republic we use a decimal comma.

Comment: so you should convert it just before using it in the "front-end" part of your website OR convert the 'comma' to a 'point' before use it in calcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I discovered is that only way, how you can do this on **Windows** is:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'czech');
```

Thanks to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`intl.default_locale` sets the locale for `intl` functions only, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075145/php-locale-configuration-in-php-ini#comment29700111_5075370).

If your code doesn't use an `intl` function for the number formatting, there's no way around changing the code. It should be as easy as setting the locale for money / number formatting to Czech.

For money:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'cs_CZ');
```

For numbers:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'cs_CZ');
```

Answer (score 0):

For linux:

This is a local configuration issue, probably caused after installing php-intl recently, which changed it for you unintentionally.

Edit your /etc/default/locale file and change the LC_NUMERIC line to

LC_NUMERIC = "en_GB.UTF-8"

You might want to change any other setting there, then reboot.