# PHP float output format

Tags: php, apache, output, command-line-interface, number-formatting

I've encountered some strange behavior in php, at some point PHP started to output float values with comma instead of dot.

```
<?php
echo 12.3;
//outputs "12,3" to both browser and CLI
```

And, as expected, all tracking scripts with float numbers from PHP (prices, QTY etc) are not working now.

Haven't found any php or apache setting to control that. Has anyone met this before? And maybe knows how to fix/change that?

P.S. Tried setlocale() for LC_ALL and LC_NUMERIC categories, doesn't work.

Comment: `echo number_format(12.3,2, ',',  ',' )`

Comment: @Gulshan know about that, thanks, but i need to find a reason and fix wrong output.

Comment: are you running this script "as is" and seeing this issue??

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224513/decimal-comma-instead-of-decimal-point)

Comment: @JayWadhwa yes, in CLI case its command php -r "echo 1.23;"

Comment: @B001ᛦ tried setlocale() usage, doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of localization. Since PHP 5.3.0 there is a `intl.default_locale` option in your `php.ini`. Should work when you change it to a country, that uses your wanted notation.

Explanation from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/intl.configuration.php):

> The locale that will be used in intl functions when none is specified (either by >omitting the corresponding argument or by passing NULL). These are ICU locales, not >system locales. The built-in ICU locales and their data can be explored at » >http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp.
>
> The default value is empty, which forces the usage of ICU's default locale. Once set, >the ini setting cannot be reset to this default value. It is not recommended that this >default be relied on, as its effective value depends on the server's environment.

Example for [Germany](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=de&_=de_DE) and [USA](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=de&_=en_US)

As you can see under numbers table:

Germany:

> Number Pattern: #,##0.###  1.234,56

USA:

> Number Pattern: #,##0.###  1,234.56

## Edit:

> ...as its effective value depends on the server's environment.

This means you have to change the local on your server environment. It only uses the set value of php.ini when no server local is set.

## For Linux:

If you want to change or set system local, use the `update-locale` program. The `LANG` variable allows you to set the locale for the entire system.

The following command sets `LANG` to `en_US.ISO8859-1` and removes definitions for `LANGUAGE`.

```
$ sudo update-locale LANG=LANG=en_US.ISO8859-1 LANGUAGE
OR
$ sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.ISO8859-1
```

You can find global locale settings in the following files:

- `/etc/default/locale` – on Ubuntu/Debian
- `/etc/locale.conf` – on CentOS/RHEL

Comment: intl.default_locale was "Null", tried "en_US", didnt work

Comment: did you edit the right .ini file? Can you print out your php.ini values to a php file and double check?

Comment: Yes, i have checked phpinfo(), intl.default_locale has both local and master values equal to "en_US"

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu(mint 19.2)

Comment: Changed /etc/default/locale values from en_UK to en_US, restarted server, seems good now. Don't know if its exactly this fixed the issue, or restart itself, but many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `number_format` to always keep it clean.

```
number_format(12.20, 2, '.') : string
```

[for more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: I know about that, thanks, but i need to find a reason and fix wrong output.