# PHP strftime outputs wrong format despite correct timezone

Tags: php, date, timezone, locale, strftime

I configured my timezone to Europe/Paris in php.ini. When executing `date_default_timezone_get()` I do get the correct value.

Then, I expect `strftime('%x', date())` to output something like *16 novembre 2018* which is the French format. But instead, I get *11/16/2018* which looks like the US format.

Any idea why?

Comment: Setting the timezone doesn't set the locale. You need to look at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075145/php-locale-configuration-in-php-ini which discusses putting it in the INI file

Comment: It doesn't seems to work. After `setlocale('fr_Fr')` the format is still the same.

Comment: On your server, run `locale -a` to see available locales. They are often named differently on different operating systems. `fr_FR` is most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the language for date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910912/change-the-language-for-date-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time zone has no effect on how dates and times are presented, for that you need to set the locale. There are no standards for locale names, but fortunately PHP's [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale) function will take multiple locale names, stopping at the first successful one.

```
// just a few common name formats
setlocale(LC_TIME, ["fr_FR.utf8", "fr_FR@euro", "fr_UTF8", "fr_FR", "french"]);
echo strftime("%d %B %Y", time());
```

Comment: Okay I finally noticed that fr_FR was not yet added to my server. I added it thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server and then using `setlocale('fr_FR')` did the trick. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just keep in mind it's safer to throw every name at it, if you plan to run this on any different servers!

Comment: On "there are no standards for locale names" - that is incorrect.  IETF Language Tags are the standard, covered in [BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47).  More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).  Agree on the other parts.  Time zone and locale are orthogonal.

Comment: @MattJohnson I stand corrected. I should have said there are no standards consistently followed by OS makers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_utf8');


echo strftime("%d %B %Y", time());
```

and got:

```
16 novembre 2018
```

Comment: On my side I get `16 November 2018` (in English). But anyway, I have to stick to `%x` as I host an application which isn't mine and which uses this format.

Comment: ''%x" is supposed to give you 11/16/2018 format: %x Preferred date representation based on locale, without the time Example: 02/05/09 for February 5, 2009. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: `%x` in French would give you "16.11.2018"

Answer (score -2):

after setting the timezone to Europe/Paris, Use echo date('d-M-Y') and it will display your desired time. it worked for me

Comment: Hi, this shouldn't work, the user wishes something like 16 novembre 2018 (in French).